# PHP Command Line argv[1] always null

Tags: php, argv

My php script is like this:

```
<?php
if ($argv[1] == 'RUN') {
    //a URL you want to retrieve
    $my_url = 'thisURL.com';
    $html = file_get_contents($my_url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    ...

    $fp = fopen('standings.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($teamInfoArrays));
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    $data = file_get_contents ('standings.json');
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

But When I run my php script from the command line with the command

```
php /home/usrname/public_html/standings.php RUN
```

The "if" function isn't met, and it does the "else" portion. Why would argv[1] be null?

Comment: Works for me... what does `var_dump($argv)` give you?

Comment: Check your phpinfo() and see if `register_argc_argv` is on.

Comment: That's exactly what I planned on doing, but I don't know how to check my phpinfo(). Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my php.ini file to make register_argc_argv = On, and $argv[1] is still Null, no matter what.

Comment: To make sure the setting is active, just put a `phpinfo()`; call into your php file and call it from the command line. It will be long, so you might want to call `script.php |grep argv`. Note: phpinfo() can give you different results when called from a cli or the web.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) argv is an array of Strings. You are comparing with `RUN`, but this should be `'RUN'` to indicate that Run is also a string. Else it will try to look up the variable `RUN` which is undefined and therefore will not be equal to `argv[1]`

Comment: I tried that before and tried it again. It's not working. Huh. Argv[1] is null when I do a var_dump.

Comment: And what if you var_dump($argv)?

Comment: I think the problem is I need to set register_argc_argv to On for this php file, and I don't know how.

Comment: According to the reference, that option is depecrated/removed. It might be better to call your function with `php /home/usrname/public_html/standings.php?command=RUN` and then check on `$_GET['command'] === 'RUN'`

Comment: I'll give that a try right now. How would that work in an IF function? if($_GET['command'] === 'RUN') {...}? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm getting a Status: 404 Not Found, and No Input File Specified.

Comment: Ahh. I got those errors from my terminal, but in the URL everything worked just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it is fixed. You might want to edit your own question with the answer for future readers =]

Answer (score 0):

you should write in your if condition

```
 if ($argv[1] == "RUN") {...
```

because the "RUN" word is a string getting from command line.

Comment: I tried that before and tried it again. It's not working. Huh. Argv[1] is null when I do a var_dump.

Comment: Did you var_dump($argv[1]) or var_dump(argv[1]) ?

Comment: I tried var_dump($argv[1]). I was just going to try var_dump(argv[1]) but now I'm getting an internal service error.